# How does EnumProcessModulesEx function, list 32-bit modules on 64-bit windows (Kernel Mode Code)

Tags: c++, function, module, kernel

i have created a 64-bit driver that walks the Modules from InMemoryOrderModuleList, that is found from the PEB structure in a process. However, the modules in this list are always 64-bit modules, and i need a function that list's the 32-bit modules for 32-bit processes.

Where might the 32-bit modules for 32-bit processes be stored at in its process?

Also, I'm using ZwQueryInformationProcess to get the PBI and PEB structures.

Comment: What is the scenario where you need to do this? I can't think of a reason why you would want to walk modules in a process from a driver. The driver should worry about servicing its I/O requests regardless of who made them or what DLLs they are using.

Comment: The scenario is that its a debugging driver that supports different types of functions. Also my driver EnumProcessModules Function can get the information that might be needed, faster than the standard EnumProcessModulesEx Function, because my function retrieves a list of structures that consist of not only the HANDLE/BaseAddress, but also the entry point, Image Size, and Module File Name. And it does this in one call.

Comment: You don't need a driver to debug user mode programs. The debugging API gives you this and plenty of other information about the process being debugged.

Comment: @RaymondChen Sure, But agian, its mostly about the speed. My function can and will perform faster when needing lots of information about multiple modules.

Comment: Sure you may be able to get it to run faster, but it's also unsupported. Make sure your customers understand that your debugger may stop working at any time. The internal structure of the PEB has changed many times and will continue to change.